# xhr return value from a php page

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

Ok guys im a bit stuck here. I usually use jquery to do this but i found out it cant be done with jquery so im doing it this way ok so this is my code

```
var url = ("upload.php?loc="+uplocation);   
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();     
        if(xhr.upload){ // check if upload property exists
            xhr.open("POST", url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name);          
            xhr.send(file); 

        }
```

And all it does is sends a file to a php page, but the php page doesn't upload the image which isn't what i want, so is their anyway of returning all the contents thats displayed on the page

if it was jquery i would do something like this

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'json/submitsongs.php',
                data: loca,
            success: function(data){
                                alert(data);
                            }

            });
```

so my question is how to do return what ever is echoed on the php page and alert it(for debugging reasons).

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, u can not upload async using Ajax.
Either use Iframes (like Google) or some nifty Flash (or Java) upload app.
Not sure, but might be HTML5 has a solution for that, but it won't be cross browser.

Comment: yer and thats y i used a xhr upload instead of jquery but thats not my question. I all ready know i can't upload using jquery

Answer (score 1):

You would add an event listener for whatever event you desired (load, error, progress, etc). So in your case you would use the 'load' event which signifies that the file has finished loading:

```
xhr.addEventListener('load', onComplete, false);
```

The onComplete is your callback function which has the event as a parameter. This event contains the response text:

```
function onComplete(event) {
    alert(event.target.responseText);
}
```